# AJAX call to return values from PHP not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a AJAX script which sends value to PHP script and to retrieve the value from the PHP script. The part where the script sends the value is working fine. Its the problem with the retrieving values. I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#raaagh").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
            type: "POST",
            data: ({name: 145}),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    data: data,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data1) {
                        var y1=data1;
                        console.log(data1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$userAnswer = $_POST['name'];    

echo json_encode($userAnswer);    
?>
```

Comment: no errors. Second ajax is not giving any value.

Comment: @jibindcruz Have you tried to turn the `data` property on the second ajax call into a `string`? It seems javascript is evaluating the value of the `data` param as a property name. Try something like this: `'data' : data`.

Comment: @jibindcruz  is the php script on the same domain as the javascript? If not you have to implement CORS or use JSONP. To verify if the ajax request is reaching your php script open a file in your php script and write something to this file if the php script is called from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {name: 145}
```

try this hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether "name" is posted before assigning the value to $userAnswer.

Both ajax scripts are sending to "ajax.php". In first ajax request "name" is posted, but in 2nd ajax request "name" is not posted.

To see warnings and errors, enable error reporting in php.

```
<?php 
//To enable error reporting
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `type:'POST'` inside the second ajax call and try to use `data1[0]`. 
Also remember that you are sending a json string (that comes from the first ajax) with the second request.
 Basically you are encoding an encoded value,so when you receive the post value you should json_decode the post value

Answer (score 0):

Your nested AJAX call does not have the request type specified.  The default is GET but your ajax.php is trying to find a POST.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#raaagh").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({name: 145}),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url:'ajax.php',
                type: "POST",       //<-- added here
                data: {name:data},  //<-- also required for POST
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data1) {
                    var y1=data1;
                    console.log(data1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});